# How do I map an array in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am having trouble trying to find out how I can split an array within GatsbyJS coming from my ContentfulCMS content module.

The desired outcome is that I can wrap each value of `featuredProducts` into its own `<div>` tag and display it on the page.

Currently, I can get the values to display, but only as one listed string. I'd like to know how I can split each one into its own separate value.

```
{
  "data": {
    "allContentfulFeaturedProduct": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "title": "Featured Products",
            "featuredProducts": [
              "pocket-t-shirt",
              "reversible-down-hoodie",
              "down-sweater"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Component looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby';

const Products = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query MyQuery {
        allContentfulFeaturedProduct {
          edges {
            node {
              featuredProducts
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}

    render={(data) => (
      <div class="featured-products">
        {
          data.allContentfulFeaturedProduct.edges.map((item, i) => (
            item.node.featuredProducts ? (
              <div class="product" key={i}>
                  {item.node.featuredProducts}
              </div>
            ) : (<div></div>)
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )}
  />
);

export default Products;
```

Comment: You have a nested array inside your edges.map function. For me it seems like you have to map your featuredProducts array as well: `item.node.featuredProducts.map(...)`. Is that the issue or what or what is preventing the desired outcome?

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant thanks for responding. Do you mean something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/sxgh48qo/

Comment: Yes, did it work?

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant Unfortunately not. Im just seeing errors :/

Answer (score 4):

After some digging and support from the Gatsby community the solution was:

```
render={data => (
  <div class="featured-products">
    {data.allContentfulFeaturedProduct.edges.map(({ node }, i) => (
      <div class="product" key={i}>
        {node.featuredProducts.map(product => (
          <div>{product}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)}
```